# Cannot get pyocr to recognize numbers

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have extracted a few numbers from images and preprocessed them into a black/white image. Here's an example of what I have:

[image]
[image]

Here is the simple script that tries to identify these numbers:

```
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
from PIL import Image

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
filename= "9.png"
text = tools.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang="eng", 
                             builder=pyocr.builders.DigitBuilder())
print text
```

But this results in nothing.

I have also tried `TextBuilder()`, but that also does not match anything.

I read that possibly enlarging the image and antialiasing it may help, and I generated this image:

[image]

But this did not help either.

My tesseract version:

```
tesseract 3.05.01
 leptonica-1.74.4
  libjpeg 9b : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.8 : zlib 1.2.8
```

Why does it not recognize my digits?